# Fire trigger after the complete transaction commit

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I try to call an external script with a trigger when I INSERT on my table.

This script have to get some data, especially the **last row added (which one fired the trigger)**

According to the documentation, CONSTRAINT TRIGGER and DEFERRABLE are executed inside the transaction so my external script can't get the last row added.

How can I fire my trigger after the transaction completely commited ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a behaviour similar to what you're asking by using the [`LISTEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-listen.html) / [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) mechanism of PostgreSQL. You can use the *payload* of the `NOTIFY` to pass values to your external process.

From the documentation:

> The `NOTIFY` command sends a notification event together with an optional "payload" string to each client application that has previously executed `LISTEN channel` for the specified channel name in the current database. Notifications are visible to all users.
>
> [...]
>
> `NOTIFY` interacts with SQL transactions in some important ways. Firstly, **if a `NOTIFY` is executed inside a transaction, the notify events are not delivered until and unless the transaction is committed**. This is appropriate, since if the transaction is aborted, all the commands within it have had no effect, including `NOTIFY`.

(emphasis mine)

The difference between this and a trigger is: the external script will not be started by the database. It needs to be a process that is programmed using a language that allows for *connections* to the database and some kind of callback system, and that can be started, and be *listening* to all notifications from the database. When a notification (message) is received, it needs to act accordingly. Your process will behave somehow like a daemon or service. I know you can do this using a program written in C, C++ or C#, but I'm not sure it can be done with a shell *script*.

See also [Asynchronous Notification](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-notify.html).

Comment: I was hoping someone would know a simpler solution. I've done this approach in the past, but the problem with it is that you really-really need to make sure that your daemon always works, because there is no error message if no one received the notification. The other problem with the approach is that it's a lot of work which is especially painful if the thing you want to run is one line of code.